# DBCC CHECKIDENT - Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am using Windows Azure Sql.

I have used DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table_Name', RESEED, 1) to reseed a table. There is no row with a primary key of 36. When I try to insert a row, I get this error:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__3214EC07EDF9A3FE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TABLE_NAME'. The duplicate key value is (36).

Is there another table that is checking the primary key? Identity insert is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the following

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table_Name', RESEED, 1) 
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table_Name', RESEED)    --<-- without the seed value
```

The second execution will reset the value to next highest available identity value.